# Arduino HTTP Request for JSON

Tags: c, json, arduino, httprequest

I'd like to obtain the JSON contents of a URL by performing an HTTP (GET) request (unless there's another way to do it...). What is the best way to perform an HTTP request over WiFi? I'm writing this in C/C++, so I'm wondering about a way to do an HTTP request programmatically.

I'm trying to read some JSON from a page I have. I'm not sure how to properly perform the HTTP request. The code I'm trying is as follows:

```
  Serial.println(client.print("GET /private/tweets_json.php?count=1&screen_name=rawd_dev HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n"));
```

The 'client' is verified to have been connected earlier in the code. However, I get a 501 response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>501 Method Not Implemented</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Implemented</h1>
<p>GET to /index.html not supported.<br />
</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Thu, 05 Sep 2013 03:15:12 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
```

I'm not sure what is causing this. How should it be done?

Comment: 6 gold badges so you know the rules of asking

Comment: What have I done wrong here? Do I need code?

Comment: Yes at least some code like you did. In the code at least you are missing 1 extra "\r\n" - headers end with an empty line.

Comment: So that should go after the HTTP request? As in, after the `Connection: close` line?

Comment: Yes. But I do not guarantee it is your problem exactly.

Comment: So I'm getting a 0 when I print the return value of that client.print() statement (I've compiled them all into one). How can I obtain the body of the HTTP request (aka the JSON I'm looking for)?